# How to edit videos with coustom musics on iPad?

Tags: ipad, video, music, imovie, video-editing

I bought iPad Pro to replace my MacBook in some light works.
For personal interest I produce small (2-3min) videos, but on iPad there is no way I can add coustom musics I find on internet (even though musics are non copyrighted).
Also it don’t let me use musics from my Apple Music account.

Is there any soulution to this issue?
How other people use iPads for video production. I want to do it fully on iPad and don’t want download and sync music from MacBook to use on iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You can add music from iCloud Drive. The easiest way to save music in iCloud Drive is to use [Workflow app](https://workflow.is), where you can use a workflow which downloads file from the URL.